# How can I convert the following standard deviation formula?

Tags: standard-deviation

Can someone please help me to convert the following standard deviation formula into something I can actually use in excel?

[image]
[image]

At the moment what I do is I have to quote every single cell in my formula and with the amount of data I have to go through it will probably take months! OMG

[image]

Appreciated. West